# Why are "fixed" and "random" called that?

Tags: mixed-model

In reading about brms, I came across the words "pterms" and "gterms" for "population-level effects" and "group-level effect". I was astonished. No, I was GOBSMACKED! Such sensible choice of terminology in statistics. How were they allowed to get away with it? More to the point, what makes "fixed" effects "fixed" and "random" effects "random"? Why aren't the far more intuitive "population-level" and "group-level" used?

Comment: `brms` is not statistics: it's *software.*  It's allowed to use whatever language and terminology it finds suitable for describing what it does.

Comment: "fixed effects" and "random effects" models are terms from econometrics rather than mainstream statistics

Comment: @Henry I was unaware of that.  What are they called in mainstream statistics?

Comment: @whuber: my understanding is that they represent levels of hierarchical linear models

Answer (score 4):

Because like many other fields (possibly all other fields), statistics terms were not created at the beginning, then used, but rather have evolved over time and many terms make sense from one perspective, but make less sense from other perspectives.  Here are some other common statistical terms/phrases that makes sense from one perspective, but could be confusing from others: analysis of variance, regression, linear models, expected value, bias, variance, standard deviation, standard error, survival analysis, censoring, roc curve, population, statistics (and probably plenty more).  And from a mathematical perspective, statisticians hold variables constant and allow constants to vary.

When I think of "fixed" and "random" effects (from a frequentist perspective), the "True" values of the "Population" are "fixed" numbers that do not change depending on which random sample I take (the estimates depend on the sample, but the "true" value being estimated does not).  But the "random" effects will depend on which random sample of "groups" I select.

Even terms like "population level" and "group level" can have understanding problems from a different perspective.  If we group the countries of the world into groups, then collect data on the populations within those groups and analyze a specific group of countries, then the populations are the brms groups, and the group is the brms population.  And if we have multiple measurements on each person, then the individual is a group.